# Convert Dataframe to display in matplotlib line chart with dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am facing an issue while plotting graph in matplotlib as I am unable to convert data exactly to give inputs to matplotlib
Here is my data

```
date,GOOG,AAPL,FB,BABA,AMZN,GE,AMD,WMT,BAC,GM,T,UAA,SHLD,XOM,RRC,BBY,MA,PFE,JPM,SBUX
1989-12-29,,0.117203,,,,0.352438,3.9375,3.48607,1.752478,,2.365775,,,1.766756,,0.166287,,0.110818,1.827968,
1990-01-02,,0.123853,,,,0.364733,4.125,3.660858,1.766686,,2.398184,,,1.766756,,0.173216,,0.113209,1.835617,
1990-01-03,,0.124684,,,,0.36405,4.0,3.660858,1.780897,,2.356516,,,1.749088,,0.194001,,0.113608,1.896803,
1990-01-04,,0.1251,,,,0.362001,3.9375,3.641439,1.743005,,2.403821,,,1.731422,,0.190537,,0.115402,1.904452,
1990-01-05,,0.125516,,,,0.358586,3.8125,3.602595,1.705114,,2.287973,,,1.722587,,0.190537,,0.114405,1.9121,
1990-01-08,,0.126347,,,,0.360635,3.8125,3.651146,1.714586,,2.326588,,,1.749088,,0.17668,,0.113409,1.9121,
1990-01-09,,0.1251,,,,0.353122,3.875,3.55404,1.714586,,2.273493,,,1.713754,,0.17668,,0.111017,1.850914,
1990-01-10,,0.119697,,,,0.353805,3.8125,3.55404,1.681432,,2.210742,,,1.722587,,0.173216,,0.11301,1.843264,
1990-01-11,,0.11471,,,,0.353805,3.875,3.592883,1.667222,,2.23005,,,1.731422,,0.169751,,0.111814,1.82032,
```

I have converted it as following dataframe

```
          AAPL
2016  0.333945
2017  0.330923
2018  0.321857
2019  0.312790
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

by using following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("portfolio.txt")
companyname = "AAPL"
frames = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(companyname)]
l1 = frames.loc['2015-6-1':'2019-6-10']
print(l1)
print(type(l1))
plt.plot(li1, label="Company Past Information")
plt.xlabel('Risk Aversion')
plt.ylabel('Optimal Investment Portfolio')
plt.title('Optimal Investment Portfolio For Low, Medium & High')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

After plotting to matplotlib I getting output correctly for which data is existed.
But for which data is not available graph is plotting wrongly.

```
      GOOG
2016   NaN
2017   NaN
2018   NaN
2019   NaN
```

Due to this I am unable to plot graph correctly

Please help out of this

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: `l1.plot()`????

Comment: Hi @ansev I don't understand your question. But here l1 is dataframe variable where I storing the data. But your comment helped me to get output

Comment: Can you add the code that you have so far that you are using to plot? Also what's the data type of your columns with your dates? Are they `datatime`? You can check with `l1.dtypes` .

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading you data in from a `.csv` using `pandas` you can:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.csv_read(your_csv, parse_dates=[0]) # 0 means your dates are in the first column
```

Otherwise you can convert your data column to `datatime` using:

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

When using `matplotlib` then you can:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.iloc[:, 0], df.loc[:, some_column])
plt.show()
```